# Textblock following mousepointer

Tags: javascript

I want a piece of text to follow the mousepointer, but only when the mouse is hovering over an image.
Until now it works partly: when the mouse accesses the image-area, the textblock jumps to the mousepointer, and remains attached to it. But unfortunately when the mouse leaves the image-area again, the text remains attached to the mouse and follows the mousepointer wherever the mouse is going. Instead it should go back to its starting position.

The relevant html:

```
<main id="landing">
    <div id='slider-block'>
        <img id='slider' class='my-image' src="img/my-image.jpg">
        <div class="my-text">
            Just some example text
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

And the relevant CSS:

```
#slider-block {
    background-color: orange;
}
.my-image {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}
.my-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 120px;
    width: 20%;
}
```

And the .js content:

```
let sliderbody = document.querySelector('#slider');
sliderbody.onmouseover = function () {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
            let titleblock = document.getElementsByClassName('my-text')[0];
            titleblock.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
            titleblock.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
        }
    );

}
```

So the question is how to end the text following the mousepointer when the mouse leaves the slider-image.

Comment: Please add relevant CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a very simplistic solution you could just sense when the mouse leaves the image and at that point remove the eventlistener so the x and y do not get updated.

```js
let sliderbody = document.querySelector('#slider');

function mousemoved(e) {
  let titleblock = document.getElementsByClassName('my-text')[0];
  titleblock.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
  titleblock.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
}
sliderbody.onmouseover = function() {
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemoved);
}
sliderbody.onmouseout = function() {
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', mousemoved);
}
```

```css
#slider-block {
  background-color: orange;
}

.my-image {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}

.my-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 120px;
  width: 20%;
}

.my-text.follow {}
```

```html
<main id="landing">
  <div id='slider-block'>
    <img id='slider' class='my-image' src="img/my-image.jpg">
    <div class="my-text">
      Just some example text
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

This just leaves the text at its final place.

Comment: Hi, I see a similar issue as I currently have. Yes, the text follows the mousepointer, but when you scroll with your mouse it loses the connection with the text-part. Is there a way to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if that fulfills your requirements:

HTML

```
<main id="landing">
  <div id='slider-block'>
      <img id='slider' width="500" class='my-image' src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541363111435-5c1b7d867904?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8ZHVtbXl8ZW58MHx8MHx8&w=1000&q=80">
      <div class="my-text">
          Just some example text
      </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

CSS

```
#slider-block {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.my-text {
  position: absolute;
}
```

JS

```
let sliderbody = document.querySelector('#slider');
sliderbody.onmouseover = function () {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
      
            let titleblock = document.getElementsByClassName('my-text')[0];
            console.log(titleblock);
            titleblock.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
            titleblock.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
        }
    );

}
```

Comment: I added the css afterwards (as you could see now). Unfortunately I do not see the difference in your solution. Perhaps you could elaborate on the difference in short?